# "Could not claim interface on camera: -6" when trying to connect usb camera (Kinect)

Tags: linux, usb, kinect

I have installed the freenect library from [openkinect.org](http://openkinect.org/). With that library there is a demo application which you can run from the terminal to test out the Kinect. However when I run this command I get the following output:

```
richard@behemoth:~$ sudo freenect-glview 
Kinect camera test
Number of devices found: 1
Could not claim interface on camera: -6
Could not open device
```

This particular error is thrown by the library [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/) by the function [libusb_claim_interface](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__dev.html#ga32fabedf5f13fdecf1cb33acdb19b57a) and the error -6 corresponds to the `LIBUSB_ERROR_BUSY`. So my guess is that it has something to do with mounting the usb, rather than specifically the `freenect` library or the Kinect itself.

**So my question is how can I find out what resource is using this interface and how can I free it so that I can access it?**

**Edit:**

What I have tried so far (just to be sure):

- Rebooted
- Plugged-out, plugged-in
- Tried different usb ports
- Restarted udev

---

Additional information that might be useful:

**/etc/fstab:**

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=1c73f217-ac8d-451b-8390-7a680628a856 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=bb49bd29-07ec-45a0-bbab-46fb8362b06b none            swap    sw              0       0
```

**sudo uname -r:**

Linux behemoth 3.0.0-14-generic-pae #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 21 22:07:10 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

**cat /etc/lsb-release**

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=11.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=oneiric
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 11.10"
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't have your environment and cannot test, but this excerpt from the [gphoto FAQ](http://gphoto.org/doc/manual/FAQ.html) seems to say that this might be a matter of permissions, rather than some program monopolizing the interface.

The following quote contains a link to the [Setting up permissions for USB ports](http://gphoto.org/doc/manual/permissions-usb.html) chapter that you could check.

> **Why do I get the error message "Could not claim the USB device"?**
>
> You have to make sure that no such kernel module is loaded and that
>   you have set up the permissions on your USB device correctly, such
>   that you have (non-root) write access to the camera device. How to set
>   this up, is described at Section 4.3, [Setting up permissions for USB
>   ports](http://gphoto.org/doc/manual/permissions-usb.html).
>
> This can also happen with cameras that works as USB Mass Storage
>   devices. A notable example is if you have an Olympus Camera that gets
>   auto-detected as an Olympus C-2040Z. In this case, you can try, if
>   you run Linux, to remove the usb-storage kernel module and attempt to
>   use libgphoto2 with it. But, unless you want to control the camera
>   (not all the model supports it), it is not a recommended solution.
>   Keeps using USB Mass Storage. Some of these Olympus supports to be
>   switched to "PC Control" mode in order to be remote controlled with an
>   external program like one using libgphoto2.

Comment: Thank you! I will test this and get back to you. When I did my initial test I used root and non-root user. Maybe it will work if I set up my non-root user's permissions properly.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds very much like that another driver is holding or using your device.
Run:

```
lsusb
```

And try to find the line with kinetic

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 046d:0850 Logitech, Inc. QuickCam Web
```

Copy'n'paste the string after ID (like 046d:0850) to google and see if you happen to come across matching linux kernel module.

If your lucky then add it to the blacklisted modules. Create your own file to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-kinetic.conf`

```
blacklist MODULENAME
```

run `depmod -a`
reboot and try again

Just be careful not to blacklist any modules that you actually need.

Answer (score 2):

This was a bit confusing, but I finally figured it out.

The newer Linux kernels come with a driver to use the Kinect as a web cam, and it appears to be grabbing the Kinect cam first, which results in the error message when you try to run freenect-glview: "Could not claim interface on camera: -6".

Do an lsmod and pipe that to a grep on the gspca string so you only see the gspca listings:

```
 lsmod | grep gspca
 gspca_kinect   12792     0
 gspca_main     27610     1     gspca_kinect
 videodev       85626     1     gspca_main

 modprobe -r gspca_kinect
 modprobe -r gspca_main
```

Then the freenect-glview should work.

Answer (score 1):

Newer linux kernels have the ms gspca drivers installed and will not detach.  They only give you the rgb camera and ir without depth, so kill them!

```
lsmod
```

Should list them all.  Find the two gspca modules.  kinect and main, I believe.

```
then modprobe -r gspca_kinect
```

Then kill the other, and try freenect-glview again.  Life is good!